# Not able to parse AWS API response from DynamoDB using mapping template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm using AWS DynamoDB and ASW API Gateway. 
I have an API to fetch some content from DB which comes in below formate:

```
    {
      "Count": 1,
      "Items": [
        {
          "id": {
            "S": "111"
          },
          "title": {
            "S": "title"
          },
          "description": {
            "L": [
              {
                "S": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
              },
              {
                "S": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitDuis felis nibh, 
    mattis 
    vitae augue a, congue malesuada orciDuis felis nibh, mattis vitae augue a, congue malesuada 
    orci"
              },
              {
                "S": "Nullam in gravida sem. Nulla sagittis dignissim ultricies"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Which I need to parse to someting like this:

```
    {
      "response": [
        {
          "id": "111",
          "title": "title",
          "description": [
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
            "Duis felis nibh, mattis vitae augue a, congue malesuada orciDuis felis nibh, mattis 
    vitae augue a, congue malesuada orci",
            "Nullam in gravida sem. Nulla sagittis dignissim ultricies"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here is my code for response mapping template:

```
    #set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
    {
        "response": [
            #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) {
                "id": "$elem.id.S",
                "description": [
                   #foreach($paramName in $elem.description.L)
                     "$paramName.S" 
                     #if($foreach.hasNext),#end],
                "title": "$elem.title.S"
            }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
        #end
        ]
    }
```

**id** and **title** I'm able to parse but not the **description**. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you setup up [data model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html#models-mappings-models) for this? It you have it, it can unregenerate the template for you, which make it easier to customize.

Comment: No. I have not created. I just want to parse it without data model.

Comment: Your json does not parse. Seems to be in incorrect format. Maybe that's why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot one END statement :-)

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "response": [
        #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) {
            "id": "$elem.id.S",
            "title": "$elem.title.S",
            "description": [
               #foreach($paramName in $elem.description.L)
                "$paramName.S"#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
                #end
            ]
        }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
    ]
}
```